# Using a while loop to iterate over table rows and update a value in another table. How can I do this with a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am working on a simple Inventory project with 2 tables: Items and Transactions.

I have built a while loop that gets the highest Item_ID associated with a Transaction_ID from the Transactions table, updates the item's SubLocation_ID in the Items table using a provided SubLocation_ID variable, and then gets the next highest Item_ID until there are no more associated with the Transaction_ID.

```
SELECT      TOP 1 @Current_Item_ID = Item_ID
FROM        Transactions 
WHERE       Transaction_ID = @Transaction_ID 
ORDER BY    Item_ID

WHILE       @Current_Item_ID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE      Items
        SET         SubLocation_ID = @SubLocation_ID
        WHERE       Item_ID = @Current_Item_ID

        SELECT      TOP 1 @Current_Item_ID = Item_ID
        FROM        Transactions
        WHERE       Transaction_ID = @Transaction_ID AND Item_ID > @Current_Item_ID 
        ORDER BY    Item_ID

        IF          @@ROWCOUNT = 0
                    BREAK
    END
```

This is how I would approach the problem in a "regular" programming language, but I feel this is not the correct way to do this in SQL. Each iteration of the loop must perform separate update and select operations, but a proper join could do everything in essentially one operation.

How can I get a single join statement to replace this entire code block?

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @bicycle_guy - yes, you are correct we should avoid loop in SQL Server, You can update your table through Join. You can use the query suggested below. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use below query to update through Join**

```
UPDATE   I
 SET    I.SubLocation_ID = @SubLocation_ID
FROM Items I 
JOIN Transactions T
    ON I.Item_ID = T.Item_ID
WHERE      T.Transaction_ID = @Transaction_ID
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! I get it now that I see how simple this join can be.